# Do I need a transit Visa when changing terminals in LHR(UK)?

Tags: visas, transit, uk, indian-citizens

I am Indian national, residing in Qatar.

I am traveling to the  US through London Heathrow (UK). My stopover at Heathrow is approx. 4 hours, before proceeding to US on same day of my arrival.

I will be changing terminals at LHR. I have no idea about the UK Immigration controls & baggage section also. I already booked/reserved my ticket with flight operated by American airlines/American airlines operated by Qatar airways.

Please let me know the whether TRANSIT Visa required for 4 hrs. stay at LHR before moving for onward journey to US.

Comment: It's not a duplicate, the Travel.SE answer became obsolete on 1 Dec 2014 owing to a rule change.

Comment: @GayotFow the answer is still not satisfying you? I vaguely read it, seems plausible to me. Whatś missing? (btw duplicate question does not necessarily mean the answer is correct)

Comment: @Vince, no. The answer links to a Home Office page dated 27 November 2014, which has been outdated and contains wrong information anyway. They published revised pages after the rule changes.

Comment: @GayotFow Since we're using that as a "canonical answer" for this style of questions (see Meta), any chance you could update the answer to match the rule change?

Comment: @Gagravarr, please take it to chat.